# Using Ruby, what is the most efficient way to check if any key in a hash matches any values within an Array

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hash, iteration, key

I want to compare the keys in a hash of parameters against an array of elements for a match.

For example:

```
params          = {"key1", "key2", "key3"}
params_to_match = ["key2","key3"]
```

I could do this, but I'm sure there is a much more elegant way to acheive the same result

```
params.each_key{|key|
  if params_to_match.include?(key.to_s)
    return
  end
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily more *efficient* but perhaps more *elegant* in some sense:

```
return unless (params.keys & params_to_match).empty?
```

A more efficient way than your example would (in the general case, not necessarily with such a small toy example) be to check whether the hash contains the keys, since the time to look those up is practically constant while looking them up from the array is O(n). So, your example would become something like this:

```
params_to_match.each { |p| return if params.has_key?(p) }
```

Comment: Looking up a key in a hash is O(n), not O(1). It's _big-theta_ of 1.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use [`&`](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000745)

> [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Set.html) Intersection—Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, with no duplicates.

```
[ 1, 1, 3, 5 ] & [ 1, 2, 3 ]   #=> [ 1, 3 ]

params.keys & params_to_match  #=> ["key2", "key3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best combination of elegant and efficient would be

```
return if params_to_match.any? { |p| params.has_key?(p) }
```

If you have ActiveSupport, you could do

```
return if params.slice(*params_to_match).any?
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a fast algorithm in psedudocode.

```
assert keys, input are sorted
pos = beginning of keys
for i in input
  pos = keys.find(pos, i)  # find() starts search at position pos
  if not_found(pos) then return false
  ++pos
return true
```

This algorithm, assuming the keys and the input are sorted to begin with, performs in O(n+m), n and m being the count of keys and input. I'll leave it for you to translate that to Ruby, but pay close attention to the `find()` function; it *must* start its search at the position found in the previous iteration, not at the start of keys. Otherwise you're down to O(n^2+m), n the count of keys.

Comment: FYI, you misinterpreted the question and then edited the title to match what you thought the question was. Also, why would the keys of a hash be already sorted? Using hash lookup is way faster than this.

Comment: it depends on how ruby implements the hash map, but if it was, say, a search-tree then traversing them would yield them in a sorted order. if they're not sorted then sort them: that would change the performance to O(n log n) + O(m), or big-theta of n + O(m) depending on the sort algorithm.