# Ruby(Hard Way, Ex48) matching array to hash then assigning values to struct?

Tags: ruby

I've looked at everything from the Ruby docs on struct, map, array & hash; but for whatever reason haven't grasped HOW to do this. I have two questions.

1. What's a good way to see if an array and a hash have a value in common?
2. From a hash, how could I find a value and "automatically" take it's key (or viceversa) and include them in a new instance of something else (e.g. Pair.new)?

I saw this SO response, but it wasn't much help...[Learn Ruby Hard Way ex. 48](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366016/learn-ruby-hard-way-ex-48)

Also looked at this too, but it didn't work & Zed says to use map func...
[Using Ruby, what is the most efficient way to check if any key in a hash matches any values within an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770075/using-ruby-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-any-key-in-a-hash-matches)

The exercise instructions can be found here.
[Ruby The Hard Way EX.48 Instructions](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex48.html)

## MY CODE (try#2080)

```
class Lexicon

Pair = Struct.new(:token, :key)

def scan(stuff)
    @words = stuff.split(" ")
    return analyze
end

def analyze

    hash = { :direction => "north", :direction => "south", 
            :direction => "east", :direction => "west", :verb => "go",  
                                 :verb => "stop"}

    @words.map do |word|
        if word == hash[:direction]
        #i need something here that says if word matches a value in hash... 
        #assign matching key/value to a new instance of Pair
            Pair.new(word)
        else
                            *#puts to see if anything is sticking* 
            puts "Oh god its not working #{word}"
            puts Pair[]
            puts hash[:direction]
           end
       end
  end
end

a = Lexicon.new()
a.scan("north mama jeffrey homie")
```

## TERMINAL

```
$ ruby lexicon.rb
Oh god its not working north
#<struct Lexicon::Pair token=nil, key=nil>
west

Oh god its not working mama
#<struct Lexicon::Pair token=nil, key=nil>
west

Oh god its not working Jeffrey
#<struct Lexicon::Pair token=nil, key=nil>
west

Oh god its not working homie
#<struct Lexicon::Pair token=nil, key=nil>
west
```

## MY CODE #2081 Same as above but,

```
   hash.each do |k, v|
      if v == @words
      #i need something here that says if word matches a value in hash... 
      #assign matching key/value to a new instance of Pair
        Pair.new(k,v)
      else
        puts "Oh god its not working"
        puts Pair[]
        puts hash[:direction]
        puts @words
      end
   end
```

## TERMINAL

```
Oh god its not working
#<struct Lexicon::Pair token=nil, key=nil>
...
...
```

Comment: For your definition of `hash`, irb will say: `hash
 => {:direction=>"west", :verb=>"stop"}`.  Do you see why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got several issues here. Most importantly, your hash is not functional; hashes are built on key-value pairs with *unique* keys, so your hash is actually the same as the following:

```
hash = { :direction => "west", :verb => "stop"}
```

You would probably be better off swapping the key-value pairs in your hash as follows:

```
hash = { "north" => :direction, "south" => :direction, 
        "east" => :direction, "west" => :direction, "go" => :verb,  
                             "stop" => :verb }

@words.map do |word|
  hash.keys.include?(word) ? Pair.new(hash[word], word) : Pair.new(:error, word)
end
```

Comment: thanks @elreimundo! is there an elegant way I could accomplish the same without swapping the key-value pairs?

Comment: Why `hash.keys.include?(word)` rather than `hash.key?(word)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def have_common_value?(array, hash)
  hash.values.any? { |v| array.include? v }
end

def get_pair_from_value(hash, value)
  hash.find { |k,v| v == value }
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit I'm going to try these too.

Answer (score 0):

A hash can only have one unique key per value, therefore, part of your problem is that the hash you generate above will only return one `:direction` and one `:location`.

This should help get you closer to what you're looking for:

```
class Lexicon

  Pair = Struct.new(:token, :key)

  def scan(stuff)
    @words = stuff.split(" ")
    return analyze
  end

  def analyze
    hash = { :directions => { :north => "north", :south => "south", :east => "east", :west => "west" },
             :actions => { :verb => "go", :verb => "stop" } }

    @words.map do |word|
      if hash[:directions].values.include?(word)
        Pair.new(word)
      else
        puts "Oh god its not working #{word}"
        puts Pair[]
        puts hash[:directions]
      end
    end
  end
end

a = Lexicon.new()
a.scan("north mama jeffrey homie")
```

Comment: Thanks @CDub but I'd need to incorporate :directions for each matching value and pass that to Pair (e.g Pair.new (:directions,'north'))